# Mostrar lista en recyclerview de registros filtrados

Tags: php, mysql, android, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Tengo una actividad que me muestra una lista de "hijos" creados anteriormente. Cada hijo está creado dentro de una sesión de un padre. Es decir, al crear el hijo, se le asigna un id_padre que se obtiene por las sharedpreferences de un clase SessionManager que tengo creada. Hasta ahi todo bien.
Yo quiero mostrar en my recyclerview, solo los hijos del padre que se ha logeado anteriormente. He incluido en la actividad para ver los hijos referencias al sessionManger, pero no consigo mostrar solo los hijos del padre logueago, sino que me muestra todos los hijos que están registrados en la base de datos, independientemente del padre que tengan.

Esta es la clase SessionManager

```
public SessionManager (Context context){
        this.context=context;
        sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NOMBRE, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void crearSesion(String id_padre, String nombre, String usuario, String email){
        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(ID, id_padre);
        editor.putString(NOMBRE,nombre);
        editor.putString(USUARIO,usuario);
        editor.putString(EMAIL,email);
        editor.apply();
    }
    


    public boolean logeado(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void comprobarLogin(){
        if(!this.logeado()){
            Intent i= new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((PerfilPadreActivity)context).finish();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> detalleUsuario(){
        HashMap<String, String> padres=new HashMap<>();
        padres.put(ID, sharedPreferences.getString(ID, null));
        padres.put(NOMBRE, sharedPreferences.getString(NOMBRE, null));
        padres.put(USUARIO, sharedPreferences.getString(USUARIO, null));
        padres.put(EMAIL, sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL, null));

        return padres;

    }

    
   

    public void cerrarSesion(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i= new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((PerfilPadreActivity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

Y esta es la actividad en la que muestro el recyclerView

```
public class VerHijoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_Hijos="https://appyay.000webhostapp.com/listahijos.php";
    RecyclerView rvlistahijos;
    List<Hijos> listahijos;

    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String getId;
    String getIdHijo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_hijo);

        sessionManager=new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.comprobarLogin();

        rvlistahijos=findViewById(R.id.rvlistahijos);
        rvlistahijos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvlistahijos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listahijos=new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String,String > padres;
        padres = sessionManager.detalleUsuario();
        getId=padres.get(sessionManager.ID);

        verhijos();




    }




    private void verhijos(){

        final String id_padre=getId;
        int getId=Integer.parseInt(id_padre);

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_Hijos,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hijos = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                listahijos.add(new Hijos(
                                                hijos.getString("nombre_hijo"),
                                                hijos.getString("edadhijo"),
                                                hijos.getString("ptoshijo")
                                        )


                                );
                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        AdaptadorHijos adaptadorhijo = new AdaptadorHijos(VerHijoActivity.this, listahijos);
                        rvlistahijos.setAdapter(adaptadorhijo);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        );

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

cuyo adaptador que llena cada cardview del recyclerView es el siguiente.

```
public class AdaptadorHijos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorHijos.HijosViewHolder> {

    private List<Hijos> listahijos;


    AdaptadorHijos(Context context, List<Hijos> listahijos){
        this.context=context;
        this.listahijos=listahijos;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdaptadorHijos.HijosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout_hijos, parent, false);
        AdaptadorHijos.HijosViewHolder viewHolderhijos = new AdaptadorHijos.HijosViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolderhijos;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorHijos.HijosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String nombrehijo = listahijos.get(position).getNombre_hijo();
        String edadhijo = listahijos.get(position).getEdadHijo();
        String ptoshijo = listahijos.get(position).getPtosHijo();

        holder.tvrvnombrehijo.setText(nombrehijo);
        holder.tvrvedadhijo.setText(edadhijo);
        holder.tvrvptoshijo.setText(ptoshijo);

        holder.setOnClickListeners();


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listahijos.size();
    }



    static class HijosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Context context;
        TextView tvrvnombrehijo, tvrvedadhijo, tvrvptoshijo;
        Button btnperfil;

        public HijosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context=itemView.getContext();

            tvrvnombrehijo= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvrvnombrehijo);
            tvrvedadhijo= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvrvedadhijo);
            tvrvptoshijo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvrvptoshijo);

            btnperfil=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnperfil);
        }
        void setOnClickListeners(){
            btnperfil.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
//esto me lleva a la actividad del perfil donde se muestran los datos cuando se da click en cada item
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, PerfilHijoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre_hijo", tvrvnombrehijo.getText());
            intent.putExtra("edadhijo", tvrvedadhijo.getText());
            intent.putExtra("ptoshijo", tvrvptoshijo.getText());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Para poder mostrar los datos en el recyclerView, los lee del archivo php siguiente:

```
<?php

require_once 'conexion.php';
$stmt= $conexion ->prepare("SELECT nombre_hijo, edadhijo, ptoshijo FROM hijos ; ");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($nombre_hijo,$edadhijo,$ptoshijo);

$hijos=array();

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp=array();
    $temp['nombre_hijo']=$nombre_hijo;
    $temp['edadhijo']=$edadhijo;
    $temp['ptoshijo']=$ptoshijo;
    array_push($hijos, $temp);
}

echo json_encode($hijos);


?>
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que lea solo los hijos que tengan el id_padre del padre que está logueado? He intentado poner una condicion WHERE en la consulta del PHP, pero me sale el recycler vacio. Tambien he intentado recuperarlo con `sessionManager.crearSesion(id_padre, usuario, nombre, email);` recuperandolo de la actividad SessionManager, pero no me funciona puesto que quizas no lo ponga en el sitio adecuado. ¿Podeis ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

He visto todo el código y en ninguna parte veo que hagas la condicional para obtener los hijos de ciertos padres, la consulta no tiene condición y se trae todos los datos de la tabla. La variable getId no la utilizas para nada en ningún momento ni al traer los datos de los hijos, ni al hacer el request de los datos al servidor. Es lógico que si agregas un where en el delete te regrese datos vacíos puesto que no envías el Id del padre al servidor y no se cumpla la condición.

En el caso de que quieras agregar el id lo harías en el StringRequest donde utilizas la URL para el llamado a servidor, ahí tienes una variable URL_Hijos, ahí necesitarías concatenar un query string para agregar la variable. Quedaría algo así:

```
URL_Hijos+"?idPadre="+id_padre
```

También tendrías que modificar tu archivo PHP para que tome en tome la variable en la petición, sería algo así (no soy experto en PHP):

```php
$parts = parse_url($url); 
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$id_padre = $query['idPadre']
```

Comment: ¿Donde puedo añadir el id del padre para enviarlo al servidor y que me mande esos datos al poner la condicion? No se en que parte del codigo hacerlo...

Comment: En la respuesta te puse una posible solución

Comment: No entiendo mucho de php la verdad... No se donde incluir eso que has escrito dentro del codigo php. ¿Despues de require_once 'conexion.php';?

Comment: @MarisaCastañoLopez, por supuesto que se puede incluir dentro de tu código php, de hecho es código PHP